# mysql query insert duplicate record

Tags: php, mysql

Please im trying to insert data from a table to another. the issue is that i find duplicate records in database when applying the code below:

```
<?php
include ('lib/connexion.php');
$id_article = $_GET['num'];
$requete = "Select * from products where product_id=$id_article";
$resultats = mysql_query ($requete);
if($resultats === FALSE) { 
die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>APP crud</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
while ($ligne =mysql_fetch_array ($resultats)){
$sql2 ="INSERT INTO panier (product_title, description, prix)
VALUES ('".$ligne[1]."','".$ligne[2]."','".$ligne[3]."' )  ";
mysql_query ($sql2) or die ('Erreur : ' .mysql_error());

$resultats2 = mysql_query ($sql2);
if($resultats2 === FALSE) { 
die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
}
header('Location: panier.php');

?>
<a href ="supprimer.php?num=<?php echo ($ligne[0]);?>">Supprimer</a>
<a href ="modifier.php?num=<?php echo ($ligne[0]);?>">Modifier</a>
<a href ="insertion_panier.php?num=<?php echo ($ligne[0]);?>">Ajouter</a>

<a href ="index.php">Retour</a>
<?php } ?>

</body>
<html>
```

Can someone tell me why this happens? thanks.

Comment: Because, you're doing this twice: `mysql_query ($sql2)`

Comment: Remove this line mysql_query ($sql2) or die ('Erreur : ' .mysql_error());

Comment: Mysql_* is deprecated use mysqli_* or PDO

Comment: thanks very much Fred/devpro.

Comment: no problemo and you could also ALTER your column(s) as UNIQUE. That will guarantee that no duplicates ever gets inserted.

Comment: Mention not.. And also chk what @fred-ii suggest in last  comments... Hi Fred.

Comment: Hiya means hello in French? Right?? @fred-ii

Comment: @devpro lol no. That's not French. *En français* it's *bonjour* or *salut*, or *allô*. "Hiya"'s just a slang word.

Comment: @fred-ii than its really LOL .. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making this as a community wiki (I've nothing to gain here, or wanting to gain) and pulled from comments to close this with:

Because, you're doing this twice: `mysql_query ($sql2)`

> *"Remove this line mysql_query ($sql2) or die ('Erreur : ' .mysql_error()); – devpro"*

and

> *"Mysql_* is deprecated use mysqli_* or PDO – devpro"*

and

> *"you could also ALTER your column(s) as UNIQUE. That will guarantee that no duplicates ever gets inserted."*

Comment: Wonderful Fred... :)

Comment: @devpro Thanks. For questions like these, I figured doing a community wiki would be more fitting.